# Getting virtual directory path in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

This is from a newbie in Silverlight. I've a Silverlight app hosted in an ASP.NET application. What I need is to get the virtual directory path in the code behind of a XAML file. In ASP.NET, `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath` would have done the needful. How can I achieve the same objective in SL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't quite get the virtual path, but found an acceptable workaround. `Application.Current.Host.Source` will always give the source of my .xap file within the ClientBin folder. This Uri will also have the virtual directory in it, if there is one. So I obtained a substring from it, by chopping off the portion starting from the ClientBin part and appended the relative Uri of the required resource to the substring.